# What scale or mode is this?

Tags: theory, modes

The notes of the scale or mode in question are:
G A B-flat D E F.  Does this combination of notes have a name?

Comment: Can it have a C note? Does adding a C break the modal feeling you're after?

Answer (score 1):

With just a B♭ ( other notes all naturals), the parent key will be the major one with that one flat. That's key **F**. Since your scale/mode starts on the second note of the F major scale, and incorporates all the same notes, it is called the *G Dorian*.

Each of the modes has exactly the same note pattern - TTSTTTS, just starting at a different point in that sequence. Dorian starts on the 2nd T, so that pattern is TSTTTST.

Just noticed there's no C note. Most diatonic scales have 7 - one letter name for each note. This answer is dependent on there being a C. No C = no named scale!

Except:- Raga Manavi (many thanks to @Mac), a hexatonic scale (hence no P4 interval from root). Is there any set of notes which doesn't have a name..?

Comment: According to "ianring.com", the Dorian scale without the 4th degree becomes the scale called "Raga Manavi": https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/1677 - so if you wanted to be technical about it...

Answer (score 0):

That would be the G *[Dorian Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorian_mode#:%7E:text=Dorian%20mode%20or%20Doric%20mode,diatonic%20scales%2C%20corresponding%20to%20the)*, a mode consisting of the steps `W H W W W H W`.

[image]

Comment: Looks like we both missed the missing C note - unless OP missed it.